# Kafka broker (0.10.0 or higher) as DStream source for Spark Streaming in Python

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

Concretely, I am looking for **a replacement or work-around for the `KafkaUtils.createStream()` API call in pyspark.streaming.kafka in Kafka 0.8.0**.

Trying to use this (depreciated) function with Kafka 0.10.0 produces an error. I was thinking about creating a custom receiver but there isn't any pyspark support here either. [It also seems like there is no fix in the make.](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-19579)

Here's an abstract of the application I'm trying to build. The application wants to create a live (aggregated) dashboard from different production line resources, which are fed into Kafka. At the same time, the processed data will go to permanent storage. The goal is to create an anomaly detection system from this permanent data.

I can work around this problem for the permanent storage by batch processing the data before sending it off. But this obviously doesn't work for streaming.

Below you can find the pseudo code of what the script should look like:

```
sc = SparkContext(appName='abc')

sc.setLogLevel('WARN')

ssc = StreamingContext(sc, 2)

## Create Dstream object from Kafka (This is where I'm stuck)

## Transform and create aggregated windows

ssc.start()

## Catch output and send back to Kafka as producer
```

All advice and solutions are more than welcome.

Comment: Have you figured out how to solve this?

Comment: @j9dy Nope, I ended up using kafka-python.

Comment: Spark Structured Streaming seems to support python though? https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/structured-streaming-kafka-integration.html Note that Spark Structured Streaming should be different from Spark Streaming (Dstreams). Structured Streaming is the new API and should be used for new applications.